# Why did Christ instruct his followers to carry purse and bag in Luke 22:36

Tags: luke, gospels, christology, niv

Initial when Christ sent out his disciples he instructed them not to carry purse or bag

.Luke 10:4 NIV

***4 Do not take a purse or bag or sandals***; and do not greet anyone on the road.

But later after the Lords supper he clearly tells them to carry those items.

Luke 22:36 NIV

***36 He said to them, “But now if you have a purse, take it, and also a bag;*** and if you don’t have a sword, sell your cloak and buy one

What could have been the meaning of carrying a purse or bag.Could Christ have been preparing them for flight

Comment: You might have answered your own question, there. (+1 for question and/or answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jesus was preparing them for different missions. In Luke 10 we have a group being sent out as emissaries and Jesus would follow. In Luke 22 we have Jesus preparing his disciples for their life-long mission that would begin after His death and resurrection. This is why He told them to carry nothing with them in the first charge and were to proceed with supplies and be armed during the second. The first was simply to carry the message of His impending arrival, the second was to carry the message of his triumphant return.